# SharePoint 2016 and Windows Server 2016

Tags: 2016, windows-server

Does it make sense to install SP2016 on Windows Server 2016?

I already know some benefits of Windows Server 2016. They are: it is just newer, will have longer support terms, has new ADFS 4.0, new IIS 10.0.
And know some drawbacks: it is new and not well known as 2012R2, it may take more resources.

What are other benefits and drawbacks?
Will SP use new features like HTTP/2? What are other features that could be used by SP?

Also could you provide some how-to guides for install SP2016 on Windows Server 2016?

Comment: You ask to many questions at once, it will be hard for one user to give you a complete answer on all the points you ask

Answer (score 2):

A big benefit is going to be the TLS stack in Server 2016. It has had improvements over Server 2012 R2. It also supports TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_*_GCM_* cypher suites which Server 2012 R2 does not.

HTTP/2 is not used with SharePoint at this time.

From an admin perspective, the significant improvements to the Windows Console (conhost) is what I see as a major added benefit; simply being able to copy and paste content from/to PowerShell makes life a lot easier.

The last part is just the lifecycle of Windows Server. We're obviously farther into the lifecycle of Server 2012 R2 than we are for Server 2016. I'd say that is an advantage as well.